# C++ call function from inside a function with pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a couple of objects, and sometimes I have to get access to all of them one after another. Now I have created an "virtual" object with an array of pointers to all of my objects. 
If I now call a function with this object, I make another call with every pointer inside its array. 
I was able to change values of the other objects this way. However, just getting a value from an object was not possible, I always get the value from the virual object.
Simple example:

// arrayVerify.ino

```
#include "ledFunction.h"

ledFunction T1(1);                                      // create first object

ledFunction T2(2);                                      // create second object

ledFunction objectPointers[] = { &T1, &T2 };        // create array with pointers to objects

ledFunction Multi(objectPointers);                  // create a virtual object to access all

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);

    Multi.example();
}

void loop(){}
```

// ledFunction.h

```
#ifndef _LEDFUNCTION_h
#define _LEDFUNCTION_h

#include "arduino.h"

class ledFunction
{
private:

    ledFunction *multiStripe;       // the array used after creating the virtual object

    byte identifier;

public:

    ledFunction(int ident);                         // create single object

    ledFunction(ledFunction *objectPointers);       // create virtual object

    void printIdentifier();

    void example();

};

#endif
```

// ledFunction.cpp

```
#include "ledFunction.h"

ledFunction::ledFunction(int ident)
{
    identifier = ident;
}

ledFunction::ledFunction(ledFunction *objectPointers)
{
    multiStripe = objectPointers;

    identifier = 9;
}

void ledFunction::example()
{
    multiStripe[0].printIdentifier();
    multiStripe[1].printIdentifier();
}

void ledFunction::printIdentifier()
{
    Serial.print("Identifier is: ");
    Serial.println(identifier);
}
```

Output here should be
1
2
and it is
9
9

Comment: `ledFunction objectPointers[] = { &T1, &T2 };` is array of objects. not pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
ledFunction objectPointers[] = { &T1, &T2 };
```

by:

```
ledFunction* objectPointers[] = { &T1, &T2 };
```

and related statements:

```
   ledFunction **multiStripe;       // the array used after ...
   ledFunction(ledFunction **objectPointers );       // create virtual object
   multiStripe[0]->printIdentifier();
   multiStripe[1]->printIdentifier();
```